# OCL - Doubts about UML constraints and Complete OCL file in Papyrus

Tags: uml, ocl, papyrus

I want to evaluate constraints in both UML class diagram and Complete OCL file. I searched but I only found examples where the methods are in the same class. Below is an example of an UML diagram class about which I have the following questions:

[image]

1. Using Papyrus, how to set in diagram the Collection types (Bag, Set, etc.), since they are not available in the input and return argument types selection window ? It's available only for Ecore (EEList, EMap)

[image]

2. How to define Context and Operations (parameters/arguments), since both are in other class, according class diagram above ?
3. How to navigate between both classes in OCL complete file ?
4. Does the OCL Complete file allow the use of commands: def, let, if-then-else, etc. ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UML does not support Collections or Maps. Rather it has multiplicities and qualified associations. For the usual common cases it is sufficient to specify an unlimited upper bound, and unique and ordered polarities to configure the UML multiplicity of a Bag/OrderedSet/Sequence/Set for OCL.

UML supports templates but OMG OCL does not, although OMG OCL is aligned to UML. Rather OMG OCL has magic "T" and "T1" types that looks remarkably like template parameters without being defined as such. The Pivot-based Eclipse OCL that prototypes solutions to many OMG OCL problems implements templates and so allows a UML user to define a DataType property whose type templates the relevant collection/map type from the Eclipse OCL Standard Library.

For flat collections using the library type is just an alternative approach. For nested collections, that UML does not support, using the DataType to define all or all but one levels of nesting is the only option.

(Papyrus uses the Pivot-based Eclipse OCL.)

Complete OCL should work normally; UML multiplicities are converted to/interpreted as OCL collection types. In the Pivot-based Eclipse OCL there is a legacy syntax that uses () to reference e.g. Set(MyClass) but a novel/familiar <> to declare e.g. `MyAggregate<E>`.

Comment: You should get the OCL gold badge just for being the only one to have the OCL know-how.

Comment: Thank you Ed. I saw that you were, for a long time, the leader of the OCL project. You should write a book or a course that goes deeper into the subject, as it would help beginners a lot. Although there is a lot of information on the internet, the examples are unfortunately often repeated. I've been searching the internet for two weeks and the information you provided I didn't have. Anyway, I'm going to have to change my approach to OCL, trying to learn about Pivot.

Comment: As well as Eclipse OCL (and QVTd) project lead, I am still/also OMG OCL (and QVT) RTF chair; 4 unpaid international jobs... A book has been on but low down my todo list for ages; a companion volume to a finally coherent OMG spec. Unfortunately with UML, and so OCL, dying motivation decreases. My ambition now is somehow to clean up the Pivot to exploit the good design decisions and replace the bad and to evolve a best of both worlds USE + Eclipse OCL before I retire for good..